# Date Casting error in mongoose with node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Date Casting issue while inserting data to mongoDB using mongoose.

Model Looks Like this :

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
emailid: String,
createddate: Date,
status: String});
```

The value i am trying to save

```
{ emailid: 'test@testwert.com',
  status: 'Activv',
  createddate: '24/01/2014' }
```

Error :

```
{ message: 'Cast to date failed for value "24/01/2014" at path "createddate"',
  name: 'CastError',type: 'date',value: "24/01/2014",path: 'createddate' }
```

I tried `new Date(Date.parse(userObject. createddate))`

Comment: Anyone ? . I am using String format for now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CastError is throwed due to the date string 24/01/2014 is not a valid date format for mongoDB. MongoDB uses ISODate as the Date format. The solution for this problem is convert the date 24/01/2014 to 01/24/2014. This can be done easily with a npm module called moment.js.